# Interaction with Facebook API without full OAuth, is it possible?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, twitter

I need to post message on a certain FB page as a owner by cron, using php and ZF 1.1.X. For this small issue, I don't want to create a full OAuth stack. Is it possible to communicate with FB API (it's desirable, PHP SDK for FB)  without it, such as twitter with his precreated access tokens (Access token, Access token secret)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to build an app and then authorize the page via the app while requesting the [manage_page permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#page_perms).

You should make yourself familiar with the [Server Side Auth process](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) as well.

Comment: Yet server-side authentication flow still will use OAuth for User authentication

Comment: You're not going to be able to post to FB without oauth. This is the next best thing. This removes the login portion.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you need an active user `access_token` to retrieve desired data this is not possible to skip OAuth flow.

Without authenticating user you only have application `access_token` (in old format `APP_ID|APP_SECRET`, but it's still works) and only limited access to most of Graph API endpoints and Application settings.

Actually there is nothing hard in implementing the user authentication with OAuth flow and it is completely transparent with usage of [PHP-SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/).

Just look at the sample code in [documentation for server-side authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/)